# Multiple figures in a two column latex file

Tags: positioning, diagrams, two-column

I have a `two-column latex file` that I am writing into (I am using `\documentclass{mn2e}`). I would like to add 4 figures, `with a 2X2 (2rows, 2columns) format`, with two figures using the first column of the page and the other two figures using the second column of the page.

This is an example of what I am looking for.

[image]

As you can see that the figure uses the entire page width (i.e. the two columns) which is **followed by normal text underneath which is written in the two-column format.**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: figure* spans both columns.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I have four different images which I need placed in such an order. How can I make two images fall in the second column?

Comment: The images above aren't really "in" the columns.  The same effect can be achieved by spacing them with \hfil (just don't put blank lines between them).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After searching for a very long time, I found out a simple solution using `multicols`.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par 
    \end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure name}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This makes it very easy to add figures in a two-column file.

Comment: You don't need `multicol`. Just use `minipage`s.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer !! took me so long to find answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  It only gets tricky when the images are not the same size or scale.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par\medskip
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\[2\tabcolsep]
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP uses document class `mn2e`,

Comment: @Marc van Dongen - The MikTeX package manager couldn't find it.  Does it matter?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. The following [link](http://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2010/07/06/install-latex/) may be useful.