# Figure is on top of text

Tags: floats, ieeetran

I am using `IEEEtran` for LaTeX. That means text is in two columns. I want to post a full figure page.
I use:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{figure}
\includepdf{fluxograma.pdf}
\caption{SEAL flowchart.}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
```

But the figure shows up on top of the rest of my text

```
\newpage
```

does not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: See: [Displaying a wide figure in a two-column document [duplicate\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30985/4778) (and the dupe), [Placing figures inside a two-column document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57732/4778), [LaTeX figures in two column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66467/4778), [Multiple figures in a two column latex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249571/4778) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`\includepdf` of package `pdfpages` is the wrong tool here. Its purpose are the inclusion of full page PDF pages as standalone PDF pages.

Macro `\includegraphics` of package `graphicx` includes images on a page:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{fluxograma.pdf}
  \caption{SEAL flowchart.}
  \label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
```